# Is there a way to import a file named after a keyword in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, keyword

Imagine that there's a Python library `states`, in which there is a script for each of the 50 states, named after those state abbreviations.

```
al.py
ak.py
...
or.py
...
wi.py
wy.py
```

This certainly isn't the best way to structure code. But given that it exists, and given that `or` is a reserved keyword, is there a reasonable way to write a caller for Oregon that includes the statement

```
from states import or
```

Or does the library have to change their naming convention to something a bit better, like the full state name.

Answer (score 6):

You can't import `or` directly, even when doing `from... import... as`. Instead, you will need to use the function-based import mechanism supplied in `importlib`. This will work:

```
import importlib
_or = importlib.import_module('states.or')
```

and you can refer to the module as `_or`.

Comment: thanks! I needed to import a function from a file called import.py and this worked perfect!